# how to remove extra spaces from string in C

Tags: c, whitespace

I have an string that have an extra spaces string, for example:

```
char * s = "  foo    baa       ";
```

I want to conver it to:

`foo baa`

I have wrote this function:

```
void trim (char ** src)
    {
        char * p = strdup(* src);
        char * ret = malloc(strlen(*src) + 1);
                assert(ret != NULL);
        char * token;
        token = strtok(p, " \t");
        while( NULL != token ) {
            while (*token) {
                 *(ret ++) = *(token ++);
            }
            token = strtok(NULL, " \t");
        }

        printf("ret = %s\n", ret);
    }
```

but it given for me an empty string from `ret` variable value. someone may point out my mistake? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are incrementing `ret` in your while, store the original address or use subscript to access different chars of `ret`.

```
    // snip
    char * ret = malloc(strlen(*src) + 1);
            assert(ret != NULL);
    char * ret_start = ret;
    //snap
    printf("ret_start = %s\n", ret_start);
```

Comment: +1.  After the loop ends, `ret` points at the terminating null character.

Comment: Thanks you! works fine. you have tips for improve this C code?

Comment: Three points - may not be that important but whatever: 1. pass `src` as `char *` why do you need it as `char **`(but look at #3 before)? 2. why do you need `p` ? you can perform strtok on `src` 3. declare `src` as const char *`, it shouldn't be modified in the method anyway.

Comment: @Binyamin: regarding #2:  using `strtok()` on the passed in string isn't a good idea if the intent is that it shouldn't be modified, since `strtok()` drops `'\0'` characters into the string it's passed.

Answer (score 0):

Other naive solution in c++(can be easily changed  to c code )-----  :)

initially  `count=0`  and  `str`-> your c++ string

```
for(i=0;i< str.size();i++)
{
        if(str[i]!=' ')
        {
                str[j++]=str[i];
                count=0;
        }
        else if(str[i]==' '&&count==0)
        {
                str[j++]=str[i];
                count =1;
        }
}
```