# String reversal program outputs newline at start of output

Tags: c, string

I have written the following code for string reversal:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define N 80

int main(void)
{
    char string[N];
    printf("enter the string\n");
    fgets(string,N,stdin);
    char *initial=string;
    char *final=string;
    while(*final)
        final++;
    final-=1;
    char temp;
    while(initial<=final)
    {
        temp=*final;
        *final=*initial;
        *initial=temp;
          initial++;
          final--;
    }
    printf("%s\n",string);
    return 0;
}
```

I run my program like this:

```
$ echo hello | ./reverse
enter the string

olleh
$
```

As you can see, there's a newline at the start. Why is this there, and how can I remove it?

Comment: Which unnecessary whitespace?

Comment: What is the output you get, and what do you want it to be instead?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to remove extra spaces from string in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674259/how-to-remove-extra-spaces-from-string-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using `fgets`, `string` will contain the trailing new line of the user's input. With this code:

```
while(*final)
    final++;
final-=1;
```

You're incrementing `final` to the NUL byte ending the string, and then moving it one back to the newline character the user entered. You then go on swapping characters at the start and end, moving inward. Unfortunately, the newline at the end has been swapped towards the start, probably causing that “unnecessary whitespace” you refer to.

The solution would be to decrement `final` once more if it points to a newline:

```
if(*final == '\n')
    final--;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `fgets` function returns the string PLUS THE END OF LINE CHARACTER.

When you reverse the string, this character will be at the start of your line. To prove this to yourself, look at the following code:

```
printf("give a word to check:\n");
fgets(buf, 100, stdin);
printf("you entered: %s\n", buf);
printf("In hex, that is ");
for(ii = 0; ii < strlen(buf); ii++) printf("%02X ", buf[ii]);
printf("\n");
```

On my machine this results in:

```
give a word to check:
Hello
you entered: Hello

In hex, that is 48 65 6C 6C 6F 0A
```

You can see the `0A` at the end...

Now I can't guarantee what character will be used on your machine - so I can't tell you for sure if you need to go back one or two characters from the end. But you could use the function `isspace` to test characters after the reversal, and get rid of them.  For example:

```
char *final = string + strlen(string);
while(isblank(*final))
    final--;
```